# How to create a POST request to login?

Tags: java, http-post, httpurlconnection

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by Kevin on 26/01/14.
 */
public final class Boot {

   public Boot(final String... args) {
       try {
           final URL url = new URL(args[0]);
           HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

           connection.setDoOutput(true);
           connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
           connection.addRequestProperty("Host", "http://example.com/");
           connection.addRequestProperty("Protocol", "HTTP/1.1");
           connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0");
           connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
           connection.addRequestProperty("Referer", "http://example.com/");
           connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
           connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "__cfduid=d2f9cfb1c350013cc71a12eaedc660a551390762958146; __utma=241386960.1917361281.1390762966.1390762966.1390762966.1; __utmb=241386960.1.10.1390762966; __utmc=241386960; __utmz=241386960.1390762966.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)");

           String encodedParams = URLEncoder.encode("login=true&email=kevin@example.com&pwd=mypassword");

           OutputStream wr = connection.getOutputStream();
           wr.write(encodedParams.getBytes());
           wr.flush();
           wr.close();

           final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
           final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

           String line;
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(line);
           }
           System.out.println("Response code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
           System.out.println(encodedParams);

       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        new Boot("https://www.example.com/admin/index.php");
    }
}
```

As you see the code above here, I am trying to create a POST-request to a website's admin panel. But, I would like to let it login, so it prints out the "admin dashboard".

I have been trying and trying for over 2 hours and I couldn't do it. Nonetheless, is this possible with Java?

Comment: Does someone have an idea?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? Your admin dashboard is a web-page and not a web-service. Do you want to do some kind of remote control? Then use Web-Driver or Selenium. Else look for a XML-RPC or REST interface for the admin application. If you still insist on your fight against /admin and HttpURLConnection, use `CookieManager`, don't encode the whole query string but only the parameters, leave out `Host` and `Protocol` header. And better use an abstraction library (HTTP Client).

Comment: How is the admin panel protected? Basic Auth or some custom login form?

Comment: It is a basic login form.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in your [crosspost](http://www.coderanch.com/t/627593/java/java/POST-Request-login) you can use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to avoid having to write all that code.  The [getting started guide](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) shows an example of logging in.

Right now what you have looks like a GET request here since the URLs are in the parameter.

```
String encodedParams = URLEncoder.encode("login=true&email=kevin@example.com&pwd=mypassword");
```

Alternatively, you could try the [Apache Http Components](http://hc.apache.org/) library.